# Sending an image to api using URLRequest or Alamofire in Swift

Tags: swift, curl, alamofire

(Swift 5 / Alamofire 5 / Xcode / IOS)

I'm trying to send a photo I took to the mathpix api. This is how it is shown in mathpix's api documentation:

```
curl -X POST https://api.mathpix.com/v3/text \
-H 'app_id: APP_ID' \
-H 'app_key: APP_KEY' \
--form 'file=@"cases_hw.jpg"' \
--form 'options_json="{\"math_inline_delimiters\": [\"$\", \"$\"], \"rm_spaces\": true}"'
```

Or using python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
import json

r = requests.post("https://api.mathpix.com/v3/text",
    files={"file": open("cases_hw.jpg","rb")},
    data={
      "options_json": json.dumps({
        "math_inline_delimiters": ["$", "$"],
        "rm_spaces": True
      })
    },
    headers={
        "app_id": "APP_ID",
        "app_key": "APP_KEY"
    }
)
print(json.dumps(r.json(), indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Here's my code:

`@State private var selectedImage: UIImage? // The taken photo is stored here`

`@State private var imagePath = "" //  Full path of image`

Request function code (function called after getting selectedImage/imagePath):

```
                let image = selectedImage
                let imageData = image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)!
                let imageKey = "takenPhoto"
                let urlString = "https://api.mathpix.com/v3/text"
                let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
                        "app_id": "my_working_app_id_here",
                        "app_key": "my_working_app_key_here"
                    ]
                
                AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multiPart in
                    multiPart.append(imageData, withName: imageKey, fileName: "takenPhoto.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
                }, to: urlString, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(_):
                        if let dictionary = response.value as? [String:Any] {
                            print("success", dictionary)
                        } else {
                            print("error")
                        }
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print("error", error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
```

This code gives

```
["error": Internal error, "error_info": {
    id = "sys_exception";
    message = "Internal error";
}]
```

I also tried to use https://github.com/zonble/CurlDSL library to create cURL requests:

```
try CURL("curl -X POST https://api.mathpix.com/v3/text -H \'app_id: my_app_id_here\' -H \'app_key: my_app_key_here\' -F image@=\(homeDirectoryString)"
```

However, it throws the same error as above.

My code above only works if I replace the image with a global link from the Internet (like https://mathpix-ocr-examples.s3.amazonaws.com/cases_hw.jpg)

It also works fine with local images (what I need) if I use the curl command in the terminal on the mac.

I've wasted about a week on this problem and have not found any working solution. I'm sure the error must be in the query syntax (swift/curl), but I don't know how to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues in the Swift code are that:

1. The key name used for the image in the `curl` command was `file`, not `takenPhoto`.
2. The `options_json` in the `curl` has not been supplied at all.

You might do something like

```swift
let imageData = …
let imageKey = "file"
let filename = "takenPhoto.jpg"

let optionsKey = "options_json"
let options: [String: Any] = ["math_inline_delimiters": ["$", "$"], "rm_spaces": true]
let optionsData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: options)

AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multiPart in
    multiPart.append(imageData, withName: imageKey, fileName: filename, mimeType: "image/jpg")
    multiPart.append(optionsData, withName: optionsKey)
}, to: urlString, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    …
}
```

---

A few minor observations:

- I would advise against `try?` as that discards any meaningful diagnostic information that has been thrown;
- I would generally advise against forced-unwrapping operator (`!`);
- When printing errors for diagnostic purposes, rather than `error.localizedDescription`, I might suggest just printing `error`. The `localizedDescription` is for friendly strings for the UI, but for diagnostic purposes, `error` is far more illuminating for the developer; and
- `responseJSON` is deprecated and you may want to switch to `responseDecodable` in the near future; and
- I would be wary of hardcoding the mimetype and the filename extension. I would generally determine the mimetype from the original asset’s URL:

  ```swift
  extension URL {
      /// Mime type for the URL
      ///
      /// Requires `import UniformTypeIdentifiers` for iOS 14 solution.
      /// Requires `import MobileCoreServices` for pre-iOS 14 solution

      var mimeType: String {
          if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
              return UTType(filenameExtension: pathExtension)?.preferredMIMEType ?? "application/octet-stream"
          } else {
              guard
                  let identifier = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, pathExtension as CFString, nil)?.takeRetainedValue(),
                  let mimeType = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(identifier, kUTTagClassMIMEType)?.takeRetainedValue() as String?
              else {
                  return "application/octet-stream"
              }

              return mimeType
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  Needless to say, if you do not need support for earlier iOS versions, you can simplify that. But it illustrates the API for determining mimetypes. When picking images, there might be a variety of different mimetypes.